# Highstock with datepicker and a non-default date

Tags: jquery, date, highcharts, datepicker, date-format

I've been working on integrating datepicker into Highstock and have problems with date format. There are many pages describing the solution for a default date format (yy-mm-dd). A good example is that one:

http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=13612

However, I'd like to have a different date format: dd-mm-yyyy. I've tried the following code:

```
window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
// ...
    rangeSelector: {
        inputDateFormat: '%d-%m-%Y',
        inputEditDateFormat: '%d-%m-%Y',
        }

// ...
}, function (chart) {

             //apply the date pickers
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#' + chart.options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker({
                    format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
                });
            }, 0);
        });
```

But the control goes mad then (i.e. it either selects random dates like 3-June-34 [== 34 year, not 1934] or even refuses to change the date at all.

I guess there must be some a problem in converting date between datepicker and chart. How to fix it ?

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle of what have you tried so far ?

Comment: My code is very long, but I found a very simple one already on Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BWEm5/. It works fine with the format: yy-mm-dd, but behaves strangely when e.g. changed to dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: I checked the fiddle link you just gave, but not able to see the popup of datepicker. From where on the graph can I see it ?

Comment: It's attached to two input boxes in the upper right corner of the chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set [`inputDateParser`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.inputDateParser). By default Highcharts will take date, and use `Date.parse()`, where `dd-mm-yyyy` isn't supported format.

See working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BWEm5/152/ (choose date before 2013 year for example).

Comment: Again Mr. Paweł saved the day (and my salary ;) ). Thank you, Sir!